# Update a value of the first column of a file and keep appending n times

Tags: perl, file, append, addition

I am looking for a better way to add 2 on contents on the first column in a file, and keep appending n times. This can be an one-liner program.

Input file (sparc_test.export, it is more than 3000 lines in an actual file):

```
20000 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rcc_data_e[6]
20000 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[51]
20000 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[3]
20000 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.shft_alu_shift_out_e[18]
20000 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[17]
20000 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[43]
```

The expected output file (let's say it runs 3 times):

```
20000 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rcc_data_e[6]
20000 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[51]
20000 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[3]
20000 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.shft_alu_shift_out_e[18]
20000 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[17]
20000 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[43]
20002 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rcc_data_e[6]
20002 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[51]
20002 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[3]
20002 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.shft_alu_shift_out_e[18]
20002 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[17]
20002 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[43]
20004 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rcc_data_e[6]
20004 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[51]
20004 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[3]
20004 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.shft_alu_shift_out_e[18]
20004 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[17]
20004 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[43]
```

An one-liner perl code for adding 2 in the first column is:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)/$1 + 2/e' sparc_export.test
```

So, I used this code and append (<<) 3 time, but it seems it is not okay, and I think there is a better way with one-liner. Any help is appreciated.

my perl code (test.pl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
my $fin;
my $foutput;

for (my $i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            open $fin, '<', 'sparc_export.test' or die "Can't open file: $!";
            open $fout, '>>', 'sparc_export.test.out' or die "Can't open file: $!";
            while (<$fin>) {
                s/(\d+)/$1 + 2/e;
                print $fout $_;
            }
            close $fout;
            close $fin;
            rename 'sparc_export.test.out', 'sparc_export.test' or die "Failed to rename: $!";
            system $bin, @args;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only missing piece is that you don't copy the input file first. (Well, and why C-style for loop?)

You can also avoid extra file operations, though -- read into an array and work with that.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $infile = 'sparc_export.test';
open my $fh, '<', $infile or die "Can't open $infile: $!";
my @lines = <$fh>;

my $outfile = 'sparc_export.test.out';
open    $fh, '>>', $outfile or die "Can't open for append $outfile: $!";

print $fh $_ for @lines;  # copy the original first

for my $i (1..3) 
{
    s/^\s*(\d+)/$1+2/e for @lines;  # changes @lines in place  

    print $fh $_ for @lines;
}
close $fh;
# now overwrite source
```

Or do it all in memory and update the original once, since the file is so small. Uses [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Path::Tiny;

my @lines = path('sparc_export.test')->lines;

my @all_lines = @lines;   

push @all_lines, map { s/(\d+)/$1+100/e; $_ } @lines  for 1..3;

path('sparc_export.test')->append( {truncate => 1}, @all_lines );
```

The `append` with `truncate` option appends replacing the contents in place.

Or

```
my @lines = path('sparc_export.test')->lines;

my @new_lines = map { 
    map { s/(\d+)/$1+100/e; $_ } @lines 
} 1..3;

path('sparc_export.test')->append( @new_lines );
```

I don't see anything better about having a one-liner, unless it is a specific requirement.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I got an syntax error:line 11, near "open    "
Global symbol "$outfile" requires explicit package name at ./sparc_extract.pl line 11.
Execution of ./sparc_extract.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: I fixed the error by adding ";" after 'sparc_export.test.out'.

Comment: @JaeyoungPark Sorry for the typo and thank you for catching it and letting me know :)